# How to add items to an array one by one in groovy language

Tags: arrays, list, grails, groovy, controller

I´m developing a grails app, and I already have a domain class "ExtendedUser" wich has info about users like: "name", "bio", "birthDate". Now I´m planning to do statistics about user´s age so I have created another controller "StatisticsController" and the idea is to store all the birthDates in a local array so I can manage multiple calculations with it

```
class StatisticsController {
//    @Secured(["ROLE_COMPANY"])
    def teststat(){
        def user = ExtendedUser.findAll()   //A list with all of the users
        def emptyList = []    //AN empty list to store all the birthdates
        def k = 0
        while (k<=user.size()){
            emptyList.add(user[k].birthDate) //Add a new birthdate to the emptyList (The Error)
            k++
        }
        [age: user]
    }
}
```

When I test, it shows me this error message: Cannot get property 'birthDate' on null object
So my question is how is the best way to store all the birthdates in an single array or list, so I can make calculations with it. Thank you

Comment: All those alternative solutions work, but the reason you're getting the error is that you let k go through the loop when it's equal to user.size(), and user[k] at that point is off the end of the list.  If user.size() == 3, then user[0], user[1], and user[2] exist, but not user[3].  Change the k<= to k< and your code will work.

Answer (score 11):

I prefer to .each() in groovy as much as possible. Read about groovy looping [here](http://groovy.codehaus.org/Looping).

For this try something like:

```
user.each() {
    emptylist.push(it.birthdate) //'it' is the name of the default iterator created by the .each()
}
```

I don't have a grails environment set up on this computer so that is right off the top of my head without being tested but give it a shot.

Comment: And what "push" supposed to do?

Comment: Push adds the value to the array.  I highly recommend reading the doc at least briefly on the data types you want to use. [Groovy list doc](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/List.html)

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be working perfectly fine, is just I already saw the doc. and IDK why it says "push" returns boolean. Than you again

Comment: I added `.birthdate` in there which is probably more along the line of what you want.  As for push, it returns true if it successfully adds adds a value to the list so you can use it in conjunction with control statements like `while(list.push(x)) {}` it will loop until it is out of values to add to the list.

Comment: In your example emptylist can be defined like this:
`emptylist = []`

Answer (score 4):

I would use this approach:

```
def birthDates = ExtendedUser.findAll().collect { it.birthDate }
```

The `collect` method transforms each element of the collection and returns the transformed collection. In this case, users are being transformed into their birth dates.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
List dates = ExtendedUser.findAll().birthDate
```